# When to use in writing the characters "=" and ":"?

Tags: writing

In written English, I always have used them interchangeably, but I guess there must be a difference in use for both.

What are the differences between those 2 characters? When to use one or another?

Comment: It is not normal to use the character '=' at all unless you are writing about mathematical or scientific equations. What is your context?

Comment: @ColinFine Don't really have one. Throughout my life as an English student, I have sometimes used them interchangeably. I know the use for the character "=" in maths, but I was wondering if It could also be applied to a list of terms for example... If you want a context, I could tell you essays, articles, reviews...etc.

Comment: Examples, please. Aside from technical writing, I would not expect to see '=' anywhere in English prose.

Comment: @ColinFine An example could be... a bulleted list. Imagine having to define a term per bullet point. For example: "Dog = an animal with fur, four legs, and a tail, often kept as a pet". Is that correct?

Comment: Probably somebody has written definitions that way. I doubt if you would find a style guide anywhere that accepted it. People will understand it, but it is not the norm

Comment: I have sometimes used the equals sign on this forum to indicate 'means the same as'. It certainly has nothing to do with a colon, which marks a division in a sentence.

Comment: In which situation would you be able to interchange them? I can't imagine any situation where I would substitute one for the other, they mean very different things.

Comment: I see, and occasionally even use, = in informal prose.  It's always a shorthand for "is the same as", "is equivalent to" or something similar.

Comment: @ChrisH I'm not sure that still counts as prose. I would say there's no use of the equals sign in English grammar, but of course we use non-grammatical constructions all the time in informal situations.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The symbol **"="** is an "equals sign" and is normally a substitute for the word "equals". It is almost always used in writing mathematical equations or in writing about mathematics. It is sometimes, in informal writing, used is a sort of metaphorical way. For example someone might write "killing = murder" to indicate that they are the same thing. It pretty much always indicates that two expressions have the same meaning of value.

I have also seen "=" used on a political protest sign used as a shorthand for "equality" in the political sense. This is also a very informal use.

The symbol **":"** is the colon. It has several uses in written English. It can introduce a list, it can separate an introductory clause from a clause that is a complete sentence, it can separate a premise from a conclusion (now a rare usage), it is used to separate hours from minutes in an expression of time. None of these uses involve equating one thing with another. I cannot think of any situation in which a colon and an equals sign can be used interchangeably.

Comment: Hey. I just added a couple of words in the first sentence, because many people are more familiar with this term of "equal to". I hope you don't mind me changing that. If you think it is wrong, I guess you can rollback the edit.

Comment: @Dhanishtha Ghosh To the best of my knowledge this (=) is always called the "equals sign":and never the "equal to sign"

Comment: How about "1:1 meeting"?

Comment: @GrzegorzOledzki I have never seen "one-on-one" meeting abbreviated "1=1 meeting.

Comment: @Polygnome neither have I.

Comment: @GrzegorzOledzki The colon can also be used as an abbreviation of the word "to" in certain contexts, usually involving ratios (e.g. "5:1 mixture of flour and sugar"). In the case of the meeting, it's referring to the ratio of the workers and managers present at the meeting (one of each).

Comment: IMO a good use of a colon would be to introduce a bulleted list of uses of the colon in the answer (as a demonstration, but the items are too long to work well as an inline list).  The ratio/"to" usage could then be added without breaking up the flow.  = is occasionally used as an ASCII bullet, though * and - are much more common; even # might be used more than =.